# Invalid link specification

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

The compiler tells me that there are 3 errors in my code:

```
Linking specification incompatible with "SpeakInternal" (declare in line 13 of voice.cpp) (previously)

wstring: not declared identifier

Syntax error: Missing ")" before identifier "uText"
```

The code is:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl SpeakInternal(wstring uText, wstring uPath);
```

I don't see what it wants from me.

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

voice.h:

```
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl DoCompile();
    __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl SpeakInternal(wstring uText, wstring uPath);
};
```

voice.cpp:

```
// voice.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "voice.h"
#include "app.h"

void  DoCompile()
{
    CApp nApp;
    nApp.DoCompile();
}
void SpeakInternal(wstring uText, wstring uPath)
{
    CApp nApp;
    //nApp.SpeakThis()
}
```

Comment: [Works for me....](https://godbolt.org/z/fyww1D) (if I add back in the necessary things that you removed - you surely know how to present a [mcve] by now)

Comment: Exact error message please.

Comment: @RichardCritten I have added them, in fact they are 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must `#include <string>` in `voice.h`, and also ether add `using namespace std;` there (which is considered bad style), or prepend all your `wstring` with `std::`.